# Vuetify.js Datepicker - Provide array of allowed dates?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#example-date-allowed-dates

I've been looking over this and trying to work out how to format syntax to provide an array of dates to the element for date selection.

```js
  methods: {
    allowedDates: val => parseInt(val.split('-')[2], 10) % 2 === 0
  }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjrQjj?editors=101

I can see the method is checking each date value for true or false, and showing dates where the method gets back a divisible by two day. Simple enough.

How would you go about providing an array of dates to check over and return the matches?

Comment: Have you tried binding/setting the `allowedDates` property to an array instead of a function?  From the docs, it sounds like that would work.

Comment: @PatrickSteele Afaics docs say `allowed-dates` -  `Type: Function`, so passing an array shouldn't work.

Comment: @Traxo I was looking at the docs page linked in the question: "You can specify allowed dates using arrays, objects, and functions.".  Maybe it meant you can write a function to check an array...  :)

Comment: @PatrickSteele Oh you are right. It's misleading tho. API has correct info.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to disable past dates you can do as follows

--------- In template area ------------

```
<v-date-picker
     v-model="date"
     :allowed-dates="disablePastDates"
></v-date-picker>
```

--------- In script area ------------

```
methods: {
    disablePastDates(val) {
       return val >= new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    },
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You would first have to declare the array of dates:

```
var el = ["2018-03-03", "2018-03-05"]
```

Then check to see if the dates are within the array:

```
allowedDates: val => el.indexOf(val) !== -1
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjrGNG?editors=101

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you, I knew it was simpler than I thought it would be, though I don't know if I overlooked it but I didn't know the array had to be YYYY-MM-DD, was using / as the delimiter, and it didn't work as expected.

Comment: The documentation is misleading though since it says: "You can specify allowed dates using arrays, objects, and functions." But you can only specify using a function, if you pass an array or an object, it gives an error

Answer (score 4):

and to filter through an array that is in state:  (using v1.5, I haven't tested on newer versions)

```
methods: {
   getAllowedDates (val) {
        if (this.allowedDates.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      },
}
```

date picker:

```
 <v-date-picker 
    scrollable
    :allowed-dates="getAllowedDates"
    ></v-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sOOrOOm/pen/mdVrzZZ)

That way it works perfectly for me!

```js
arrayDates: []

methods: {
   allowedDates(val) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.arrayDates.length; i++) {
         if (this.arrayDates[i] == val){
            return val
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `val` parameter that is provided to that function is the date with the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is why they are using that function to split by the hyphen (`-`) character and then take the 3rd position in that array and getting only the even numbers.

You should be able to use the `val` parameter provided to that function call to return a boolean value that represents whether you want that date to be selectable or not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, between this and John's answer it makes a lot more sense now.